# rake gems:install, how do I prevent a particular gem from installing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

one of the gems that one of my required gems installs is i18n-0.5.0.... which causes problems with my other gems...

but i18n-0.4.2 works.... but I can't have both, because the app favors the more recent i18n gem.

this is how I require the proper i18n:

config.gem 'i18n', :version => '0.4.2'

no greater than.

so.. two qusetions, why does it prefer the newer one, when I specify the older one?
how do I prevent 0.5 from installing?

Comment: http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of that but your problem could come from the 0.5.0 version of the gem wich is still install on your environment. Try a `gem list I18n` to see all the versions and if the 0.5.0 is here you can try :

```
gem uninstall I18n 0.5.0
```

This version was installed before and never remove. But with you new config it will not be re-installed with the `rake gem:install` command.